# Automapper string to List - expression tree error

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Excuses-me,

Here is my code to create a mapper (transforming a string containing ids to a List) :

```
CreateMap<VisualState, VisualStateDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.JsonElementIdList,
                     m => m.MapFrom(src => src.JsonElementIdList
                                                .Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList()));
```

And I can't understand why this part :

```
src.JsonElementIdList.Split(',')
```

sent the following error :

> CS0854 C# An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that
>   uses optional arguments

Any one has an idea ? Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

The mapper definition is `<TSource, TDestination>` so I belive if you change your code to `CreateMap<VisualStateDto, VisualState>()` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Expression.Call API does not support optional parameter and you should Replace `Split(',')` with

`Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.None)`

or

`Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`